# Change R character encoding efficiently without memory copying (Encoding function)

Tags: r, excel, encoding, character-encoding

I frequently import huge Excel files and use therefore the packages `openxlsx` and `readxl` (`xlsx::read.xlsx[2]` is too slow) on Windows 7.

Those packages do not have the option to specify an encoding so that I have to change the encoding marker of the string columns from "unknown" (native = Windows codepage 1252) to UTF-8 which is the standard encoding of Excel's XLSX files.

**What is the most efficient way to change R's encoding marker of "strings" (character vectors) without causing the original strings to be copied?**

R has `Encoding()` and `enc2utf8` to change the encoding marker and I use it only to fix the wrong encoding marker without changing the original bytes of the strings.

Even though `Encoding()` should not change the bytes of the string itself (= not convert the string like `iconv`) the string is copied once or more:

```
> x <- "fa\xE7ile"
> x
[1] "fa\xe7ile"
> charToRaw(x)
[1] 66 61 e7 69 6c 65
> tracemem(x)
[1] "<0x47030f8>"
> Encoding(x)
[1] "unknown"
> Encoding(x) <- "latin1"
tracemem[0x47030f8 -> 0x4463118]: 
tracemem[0x4463118 -> 0x44630e8]: Encoding<- 
> x
[1] "façile"   
> charToRaw(x)
[1] 66 61 e7 69 6c 65
> enc2utf8(x)
tracemem[0x44630e8 -> 0x4706e38]: 
[1] "façile"
> charToRaw(x)
[1] 66 61 e7 69 6c 65
```

PS: The help of `enc2utf8` claims "They are primitive functions, designed to do minimal copying." but still does copy the string once.

Comment: It looks like you might be able to remove one of the two copies by calling the assignment function directly, e.g. `'Encoding<-'(x,"latin1")`.

Comment: ...the remaining copy is probably unavoidable as it seems that all (?) strings are created with NAMED set to 2. Maybe this has to do with R's use of a global hash table for character vectors...? But we're pretty far beyond my knowledge now.

Comment: Yes, good point, THX (only one instead of two copies - the assignment operator seems to be to cause): `> 'Encoding<-'(x,"latin1")
tracemem[0x4e7f1e8 -> 0x4f54478]: Encoding<- 
[1] "façile"`

Comment: What do you mean with "NAMED set to 2"?

Comment: It is part of R's internal reference counting system, the way it tracks whether an object needs to be copied before changes are made (in case other symbols point to the same object). See [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) and the section "Modifying in place".

Comment: @joran Please make an answer of your comments so that I can give you the "credits". I think you are right: There is no better solution. THX

Comment: Done. I had confined myself to comments because I wasn't certain to what extent I had answered your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid one of the copies by calling the assignment version of the function directly,

```
`Encoding<-`(x,"latin1")
```

My speculation is that the remaining copy is unavoidable, as it appears that all character (the more common name for strings in R) objects are created with their `NAMED` attribute set to 2. You can check this via,

```
x <- "a"
.Internal(inspect(x))
```

in a clean R session. (And not in RStudio, I believe RStudio artificially messes with the `NAMED` attribute in ways that may be misleading.) If I were to *really* speculate, I'd guess that this is somehow related to R's use of a global hash table for all character vectors, which allows for lots of performance improvements for character vectors generally, but maybe a consequence is some extra copying in some circumstances.

Further reading on these sorts of copying issues can be found [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html).